# Start monkeyrunner script on multiple devices

Tags: android, monkeyrunner, monkey, android-monkey

I have a script that should be run on two devices at same time, this two devices are connected to one pc.

How can I run the script on both devices at the same time ?

is there some option like -s "SERIAL_NUMBER" , or something l

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjust your script slightly - add a device-id parameter & use that when creating your `MonkeyDevice`.

`MonkeyRunner#waitForConnection(float, string)` can take a timeout and a device identifier to start the script on an specific device.

Comment: ok, but how to read the deviceid, and what should I specify for timeout is 100 seconds okey?

Comment: Typically you would call `adb devices` and parse the output to retrieve the device identifiers. We typically let the runner "wait forever" - since it's running in a Jenkins job with a timeout it will be killed after a suitable amount of time anyway.

Answer (score 2):

try this:-

```
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice
import os
devices = os.popen('adb devices').read().strip().split('\n')[1:];
deviceid = devices[0].split('\t')[0];
device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection('',deviceid)
```

hope works.